How can I remove round shaped white colour on worktop in kitchen due to hotness of pan?
I placed a hot pan on a worktop. Due to this white circle shape has come on worktop.
How can I remove it? The original colour of the worktop is black.

If the worktop is plastic-laminated, it's likely that you can't.

Cover the discolored area with a trivet or ceramic tile. A bit of construction adhesive holds tile well.

This question is similar to: Kitchen Counter top has small patch that is losing color. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
